# NullPointerException. Why when EmplooyeDAOImpl is instansiated?

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, ejb

I have a simple `.xhtml` page which just has three fields (username, password, fullName) and a button which submits that data to be persisted as an employee object. When I try it I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dao.implementation.EmployeeDAOImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:63)
    at com.services.AddEmployeeService.addEmployee(AddEmployeeService.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
```

It looks like it is caused by the `EmployeeDAOImpl` class. Any idea where the problem is? `EmployeeDAOImpl` is explicitely instansiated. Is it related to the fact that it implements the `EmployeeDAO` interface ? The rest of the code is below:

**EmployeeDAOImpl**

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( EmployeeDAOImpl.class.getName());

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) throws EmployeeException {

    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    try{
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(employee);
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException e){
        tx.rollback();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new EmployeeException();
    }

}
```

**AddEmployeeService**

```
import com.dao.implementation.EmployeeDAOImpl;
import com.exceptions.EmployeeException;
import com.model.Employee;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "addEmployeeService")
@RequestScoped
public class AddEmployeeService
{
  private Employee emp = new Employee();

  private EmployeeDAOImpl emDAO = new EmployeeDAOImpl();

  public void addEmployee(){
    try {
        emDAO.addEmployee(emp);
    } catch (EmployeeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddEmployeeService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public Employee getEmp()
{
    return emp;
}

public EmployeeDAOImpl getEmDAO()
{
    return emDAO;
}

public void setEmp(Employee emp)
{
    this.emp = emp;
}  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you explicitly instantiate the `EmployeeDAOImpl` object, the `EntityManager` can't be injected (since the container doesn't know that you created the object) and you get a NPE.

You need to stop creating these kinds of objects explicitly, since they require support from the container. They need to be managed objects or EJBs, and need to be injected instead of being created through constructors.

Comment: How can I fix this ? Should I `@Inject` the `EmployeeDAOImpl`, if yes do I need some anotation on that class.